# Parameter and initial conditions fitting ODE models with nls.lm

Tags: r, ode, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I am currently trying to fit ODE functional responses using the Levenberg-Marquardt routine (nls.lm) in pkg-`minpack.lm` following the tutorial here (http://www.r-bloggers.com/learning-r-parameter-fitting-for-models-involving-differential-equations/).

In the example, he fits the data by first setting up a function rxnrate which I modified shown below:

```
library(ggplot2) #library for plotting
library(reshape2) # library for reshaping data (tall-narrow <-> short-wide)
library(deSolve) # library for solving differential equations
library(minpack.lm) # library for least squares fit using levenberg-marquart algorithm
# prediction of concentration
# rate function
rxnrate=function(t,c,parms){
  # rate constant passed through a list called parms
  k1=parms$k1
  k2=parms$k2
  k3=parms$k3

 # c is the concentration of species

 # derivatives dc/dt are computed below
  r=rep(0,length(c))
  r[1]=-k1*c["A"]  #dcA/dt
  r[2]=k1*c["A"]-k2*c["B"]+k3*c["C"] #dcB/dt
  r[3]=k2*c["B"]-k3*c["C"] #dcC/dt

  # the computed derivatives are returned as a list
  # order of derivatives needs to be the same as the order of species in c
  return(list(r))

}
```

My problem is that the initial condition of each states can be also considered as the estimated parameters. However, it does not work properly at the moment.
Below is my code:

```
# function that calculates residual sum of squares
ssq=function(myparms){

  # inital concentration 
  cinit=c(A=myparms[4],B=0,C=0)

  # time points for which conc is reported
  # include the points where data is available
  t=c(seq(0,5,0.1),df$time)
  t=sort(unique(t))
  # parms from the parameter estimation routine
  k1=myparms[1]
  k2=myparms[2]
  k3=myparms[3]
  # solve ODE for a given set of parameters
   out=ode(y=cinit,times=t,func=rxnrate,parms=list(k1=k1,k2=k2,k3=k3))


  # Filter data that contains time points where data is available
  outdf=data.frame(out)
  outdf=outdf[outdf$time %in% df$time,]
  # Evaluate predicted vs experimental residual
  preddf=melt(outdf,id.var="time",variable.name="species",value.name="conc")
  expdf=melt(df,id.var="time",variable.name="species",value.name="conc")
  ssqres=preddf$conc-expdf$conc

  # return predicted vs experimental residual
  return(ssqres)

}

# parameter fitting using levenberg marquart algorithm
# initial guess for parameters
 myparms=c(k1=0.5,k2=0.5,k3=0.5,A=1)

# fitting
fitval=nls.lm(par=myparms,fn=ssq)
```

Once I run this, an error comes out like this

```
Error in chol.default(object$hessian) : 
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite
```

Comment: A typing mistake in ssq=function(myparms), the # in the front of         cinit=c(A=myparms[4],B=0,C=0) should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of your code is the following one:

In the code-line `cinit=c(A=myparms[4],B=0,C=0)` you gave A the value of `myparms[4]` AND the name of `myparms[4]`. Let's see:

```
myparms=c(k1=0.5,k2=0.5,k3=0.5,A=1)
cinit=c(A=myparms[4],B=0,C=0)
print(cinit)
A.A   B   C 
1   0   0
```

to solve this problem, you can do this:

```
myparms=c(k1=0.5,k2=0.5,k3=0.5,A=1)
cinit=c(A=unname(myparms[4]),B=0,C=0)
print(cinit)
A   B   C 
1   0   0
```

or this:

```
myparms=c(k1=0.5,k2=0.5,k3=0.5,1)
cinit=c(A=unname(myparms[4]),B=0,C=0)
print(cinit)
A   B   C 
1   0   0
```

Then your code will work!

Best regards,
J_F

Comment: Hi J_F, Thanks for your response. It works properly now

Comment: So you can vote my answer up and mark it as the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: Could also use this: `myparms=c(k1=0.5,k2=0.5,k3=0.5, 1)`. It should be noted that the cited example on which this was based used a list rather than a named vector, and it is much more typical for parameters for optimization routines with R to be delivered as lists.